# What kind of user profile is needed for to access accounts ,contacts , opportunities ..etc properly through php for salesforce enterprise version

Tags: user-profile

What kind of user profile is needed for to access accounts ,contacts , opportunities ..etc properly through php for salesforce enterprise version.
I connected salesforce through free developer account but I cannot download wsdl for salesforce enterprise version. What kind of user profile is needed to access salesforce properly through php.

Comment: The Enterprise WSDL is specific to the Organization that you're trying to access while the Partner WSDL is not. As for profiles, you'll need to use a profile that has the CRM user license associated with it such as the Standard User.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of profile depends on what/how the profiles have been set in your Salesforce implementation. What you need here is specifically the ability to be able to access Salesforce using APIs securely.

In these scenarios its usually an “Integration User Profile” is what you set up in Salesforce with necessary permissions. It depends on which type of objects you want to access, and what other specifics you want  is decided by the “license” of the user that you want to use for integration.

You can refer to more here on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176281&type=1) which provides good overview of setting up an integration user. This [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm&type=5) provides details around user licenses as which objects are available with which license.

As for your other issue around downloading the wsdl, it needs to be done by a system admin in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

To download a WSDL, you need to have API Enabled, Modify All Data, and View Setup and Configuration permissions. By default, the only profile that has this configuration is System Administrator. You would need to contact your administrator to get the appropriate level of access. Note that this is only needed to download the WSDL. In order to use an API call, you only need to have API Enabled plus permissions for whichever objects and fields you need to use; even the default Read Only profile can at least query records from the database.